# Not able to type in ckeditor on safari or ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, ckeditor

I used Ckeditor in javascript but the problem is that in mac safari browser or ipad I am not able to type in textarea.

Comment: It might help to present us with some context; show us your code.

Comment: Can you please see your browser console if there is any error ?

Comment: failed to load resorce from content.css this error is showing on console on safari

Answer (score 0):

Because HTML 5 content editable attribute is disabled in safari and ipad. CK-Editor will not run correctly. 
the only possible workaround is to switch ck editor to source mode.